# Which is the correct way to pass data and call APIs between two ViewControllers in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and I started developing applications using it. I don't know how to use MVVM in the correct way in the following scenario. I have ViewController (ViewController A) with a table view. Each table view cell is associated with a Student Model. The student Model will look like this.

```
struct Student {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Now when the user clicks on one of the cells, I need to call another API to get the subjects that particular student subscribed to. Once I get the response I need to navigate to ViewContrller B and show it in a table view.

I can see two options to do this.

**Option 1**

When the user selects a table view cell pass the Studen model to ViewController B as a dependency. ViewController B shows a loading screen and calls the API by passing the student id to load the Subjects. Then it shows subjects in a table view, once it gets a successful response. If there is any failure, there will be an alert message showing in view controller B and, the user needs to go back to ViewController A to try again or to select a different student.

**Option 2**

When the user selects a table view cell ViewControler A itself calls the subject API. Failure will return an error message and ViewController A will show an alert message. User can try again with the same Student or the user can select a different Student. A successful response will return with an array of Subject models. ViewController A passes the Subjects Model array to ViewController B. ViewController B will show up on the screen with a table view with all subjects.

When it comes to user experience Option 2 seems alright, but then ViewController A has to do two API calls to load the Students and Subjects. And also it has references to two View Models Student and Subjects.

I'm not sure which one is the correct way to do it when it comes to MVVM and the same time have a better user experience. Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Option 1 is definitely the better option from a UX perspective. Blocking transitions while waiting for UI should always be avoided. 

I would navigate the user to ViewController B immediately, perform the API request while showing a loading indicator, and finally once the API call completes, show the data in the table.

It's likely fine to use the student object as a dependency when constructing ViewController B, but I'd suggest instead using the Student object to construct a ViewModel B which is then used by View Controller B. This would follow MVVM conventions more closely.

Comment: @Zano agreed. But what should I do when there is a failure in the Subject API call? Is it ok to pop the ViewController B automatically once the user closes the Alert? Otherwise no point in showing ViewContoller B with an empty table view.

Comment: I would either pop back to ViewController A and present an error message as an alert. Or alternatively, hide the loading indicator and show some sort of error UI on ViewController B. Maybe some text in place of the table view, "Failed to load subjects" or something like that. And maybe include a retry button.

Answer (score 1):

I thing your option 1 is the correct way, in my experience to show all data that select all data list from database, then when want to select one / select detail only one row, can call other method/function/API that receive single unique id from database